# Why validation error responce in an array give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?

Tags: laravel-api

Is it possible that the Laravel API validation error can be passed out of the array and sent to the object?

any suggestions?

Want the Laravel API validation error in object not in the array at where we get the responce.
[In this API response I get errors object and then array of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TecQ.png).